# generating GUID without hyphen

Tags: c#, winforms

I am generating a GUID using the following statement in my code

```
byte[ ] keyBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes( Guid.NewGuid( ).ToString( ).Substring( 0, 12 ) );
```

But, when a GUID is generated, I find that it contains the hyphen character too. How do I go about in generating a GUID with only letters (upper case and lower case) and numbers? I do not want the hyphen. Can someone give me so idea?

Answer (score 373, accepted):

Note that you are talking about the (canonical) string representation of a Guid. The Guid itself is actually a 128-bit integer value.

You can use the "N" specifier with the [`Guid.ToString(String)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/97af8hh4.aspx) overload.

```
Guid.NewGuid().ToString("N");
```

By default letters are lowercase. A Guid with only uppercase letters can only be achieved by manually converting them all to uppercase, example:

```
Guid.NewGuid().ToString("N").ToUpper();
```

A guid with only either letter or digits makes no sense. A guid string representation is hexadecimal, and thus will always (well most likely) contain both.

Comment: is it possible to create a GUID with both Upper and lowercase chars along with numbers???

Comment: @HarishKumar That makes no sense. The GUID string is a hexadecimal number. In that notation 'a' is the same as 'A'. Although because of that you can print every letter in the casing you want (but I really see no point in that).

Comment: but what i wish to have is a guid string, that is a mixture of lower case, upper case and numbers...can i achieve dis sort???

Comment: @HarishKumar How would you decide which letters should be upper and which should be lowercase? You are of course free to use `string.Replace(char, char)` to achieve that, but really it is pointless and unnecessary. Consider posting a new question and try to ask what you really want to achieve - it seems to be more than just getting rid of hyphens in GUID strings.

Answer (score -3):

```
Guid.NewGuid().ToString().Replace("-", string.Empty)
```

Comment: While this will do the job, if nothing else, it is extra work (and most likely an unnecessary string allocation).