# Having upper case, lower case and digits in a GUID

Tags: c#, winforms

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [generating GUID without hyphen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8877460/generating-guid-without-hyphen)

I am creating a GUID with the following piece of code

```
 byte[] keyBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(Guid.NewGuid().ToString("N").Substring(0, 9));
```

The end result is a GUID that contains lower cased chars and numbers. I am trying to have upper case, lower case and numbers, all in one GUID. And I dont want hyphen char within the generated GUID. Can anyone suggest me an idea?

Comment: You are asking almost the exact same question. As with your [first](http://stackoverflow.com/q/8877460/21567) question, without further information on what you are **actually** trying to achieve here, there is only one answer: you can have mixed case letters in a GUID string, but it resembles the same GUID value.

Comment: i just wish to generate a random guid value with upper, lower and numbers...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Concerning your comment:

> i just wish to generate a random guid value with upper, lower and
>   numbers...

Something like this could be done

```
var rand = new Random();
var sb = new StringBuilder();

foreach (char c in Guid.NewGuid().ToString("N"))
{
    sb.Append(rand.Next(0, 2) == 1 ? Char.ToUpper(c) : c);
}
```

Not giving any guarantees about the quality about the "randomness" of upper/lowercase characters.

Answer (score 0):

You are [already doing it correct](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/97af8hh4.aspx)?

```
Guid.NewGuid().ToString("N")
32 digits:
00000000000000000000000000000000
```

The result will contain 32 digits, but they can be letters as well.

Comment: this creates only lower case nd digits..i want lower, upper and digits all within a guid