# Remove '-' hyphen between numbers using FormatStringClaim transformationmethod in ClaimsTransformation

Tags: azure

In AAD B2C Premium policy I want to remove hypen '-' from objectId claimtype and assign it to another claimtype.

Eg:

Input : e8023a66-30ed-4e31-a17e-c013081704a0
Ouptut : e8023a6630ed4e31a17ec013081704a0

I am using FormatStringClaim transformationmethod in ClaimsTransformation to achieve the same  however the value is getting assigned to the target claimtype with hypen.

Can you please help me in removing hypen?

Comment: What about `String.Split`?

Comment: Can you explain why `String.Replace` or `String.Regex` are not feasible ?

Comment: Why can't you use `string.Replace()`?  Seems like that's exactly how one would replace substrings within a string.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [generating GUID without hyphen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8877460/generating-guid-without-hyphen)

Comment: This sounds like an [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/). You know that GUIDs are simply integers, right? The hyphen is only shown when you convert one to a string. What's wrong with hyphens in strings? If you don't want hypens, don't convert GUIDs to strings. Or if you have a string, convert it to a GUID without hyphens; did you try that?

Comment: This question shows no evidence of any prior effort.

Answer (score 4):

This should do it.

```
var id = Guid.Parse("e8023a66-30ed-4e31-a17e-c013081704a0");
Console.WriteLine(id.ToString("N"));
```

Result is

```
e8023a6630ed4e31a17ec013081704a0
```

- N - 32 digit
- D - 32 digits separated by hyphens
- B - 32 digitsseparated by hyphens, enclosed in braces
- P - 32 digits separated by hyphens, enclosed in parentheses
- X - Four hexadecimal values enclosed    in braces, where the fourth value
  is a subset of eight hexadecimal    values that is also enclosed in
  braces:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/97af8hh4(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Thanks for responding. I am trying to invoke string.format method from Azure B2C Custom Policy 


(<ClaimsTransformation Id="CreateGUID" TransformationMethod="FormatStringClaim">) 

where it is not feasible to write any code. Is it possible to achieve the same using string.format method.